# How to connect to external service from an Application deployed on docker?

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, janusgraph

I have an application which is using an embedded janusgraph server.

The application is running fine when it is deployed directly on the server (bare metal).

However, i am getting connection error when i run the image on docker.

Here is the docker file, which i am using:

```
FROM *****.ecr.us-east-1.***.com/java8:latest
ADD my-api/target/my-api-0.0.4-FINAL.zip  /opt/
WORKDIR /opt/
RUN unzip my-api-0.0.4-FINAL.zip
WORKDIR /opt/my-api-0.0.4/bin/
RUN chmod +x /opt/my-api-0.0.4/bin/runserverscript.sh
RUN mkdir /data
EXPOSE 8181
CMD exec /opt/my-api-0.0.4/bin/runserverscript.sh
```

and here is the janusgraph config: (which i connecting to external db)

```
storage.backend=cql
storage.cql.keyspace=a_graph
storage.cql.read-consistency-level=ONE
storage.hostname=10*.**.2.**
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
```

I am creating the image using the following command:

```
docker build --tag my-api:latest .
```

and running the container using:

```
docker run --publish 7171:7171 --name myapi my-api:latest
```

and getting the connect issue as follows:

> Loading.. Graph Config : ja-staging.properties Server could not be
>   started, ERROR: Error creating bean with name '': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private XXXService XXXService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'followService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private gggService gService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'graphService': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could
>   not instantiate implementation:
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing the docker from my mac machine resolved the issue for me.

I am not why it was happening. But after a couple of days of struggler, i re-installed the docker, and all worked fine.